# Blocked websites on Safari

Tags: ios, safari

I was using a public WiFi spot at the airport and noticed that certain websites on Safari were being blocked. I was able to go to these websites when I used my own data, but I have limited data so is there a way to bypass this?

Answer (score 1):

Public WiFi hotspots, especially free ones, tend to block certain sites just to limit bandwidth usage or potential liability issues. Workaround number one you have already found: use your own cellular data, which is not always an ideal situation.

2. VPN software is sometimes a good solution to this depending on if the public WiFi allows VPN connections. If it does you can get one that supports iOS (I use TorGuard but there are hundreds of others) and use that to bypass the limitations of some public WiFi hotspots.

**Note:** depending on what you are trying to do online that WiFi hotspot might see you sending and receiving large amounts of data (Netflix, YouTube, etc.) and block your MAC address and you are, again locked out of that particular WiFi hotspot.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use a vpn. Because, this is due to the rules of the wifi firewall.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info, such as what a VPN is and how they may go about using one? Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.

Comment: Thank you for your remark but it's complicated to make it clear how to use it, because I don't know if it's on Mac or iPhone.
Also, the usage will depend on the service he will buy or not. If it supports openVPN or only the VPN application. Yes, I could have given details about what is a VPN, but I didn't want to get out of the area of the question. Who's how to bypass the limitation of wifi

Comment: @The33Coder You can use comments to ask clarifying questions so your answer will be more complete and accurate.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).